# calling a .net service from php

Tags: php, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to call a .NET api controller from php

```
  $user = $ctl->getUser();
        $client = $ctl->getCurrentClient();
        $userid = $user->getID();
        $clientid = $client->getID();
        $data = array('userid' => $userid, 'clientid' => $clientid);

        $data_string = json_encode($data);           


          $ch = curl_init('https://localhost:44346/api/participantapi/TransferParticipants');

          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");             
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                   
        );          

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        print_r($result);
        curl_close($ch);
```

My controller looks like

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("TransferParticipants")]
    public IActionResult TransferParticipants(JObject data)
```

If I make the call from postman it works fine.  But when I make this call from the php code, I don't see anything.  Is there anyway for me to see what I'm missing.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried the options from that post and still no luck.  It seems like it isn't sending at all.

Comment: You might see if [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) gives you anything.

Comment: That is showing an SSL error.
'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Is there anyway to get around that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)